# Set a them for all subset of category

Tags: categories, theme-development, themes, templates

I know I can set a theme template for any category , which sets the name of php file like this: `category-16.php`

But there are many subsets for my category16. I want that template set for all of subset of category16.

How?

Comment: Hi. In WordPress terminology you have one theme containing several templates. Do you mean you'd like to use a different template for each sub-category?

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions you need to accomplish this. First, you will have to know whether a category is a subactegory of 16. This is [`cat_is_ancestor_of`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of). Second, you will have to force that category to use the template of 16, which you do with [`locate_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template). Knowing this, you can build a filter on the function that determines which template to use for a category page like this:

```
add_filter ('category_template', 'wpse24089_category_template');

function wpse24089_category_template( $template ) {
    $current_cat = get_queried_object_id();
    if (cat_is_ancestor_of (16, $current_cat))
        $template = locate_template( 'category-slider.php' );
    return $template;
    }
```